# return value based on result of sum of rows in separate column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to make a new column (column D) that returns a `CLOSE` value if at anytime in the next 5 rows (above) the change of the value at the time of the `SELL` (ie 452.37) reaches a `5%` lower value. (ie `452.37 / 1.05 = 432.85`) which does occur on row 5.

My dataframe is as follows and row D is what I would like to to look like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = ('1/05/2019','2/05/2019','3/05/2019','4/05/2019','5/05/2019',
           '6/05/2019','7/05/2019','8/05/2019','9/05/2019','10/05/2019')
df['B'] = (460.97, 454.50, 439.00, 438.04, 433.00,
           428.01, 440.00, 437.69, 452.37, 455.93)
df['C'] = ('-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'SELL', '-')
df['D'] = ('-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'CLOSE', '-', '-', '-', '-')

print(df)
```

Comment: Why would you reverse my edit? Your post was unreadable.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think anyone could help you when the post lacks any formatting :\

Comment: I'm gonna need more explanation here sorry. I don't do options trading but dont you normally close at the end? https://optionstradingresearch.com/buy-to-open-sell-to-close-sell-to-open-buy-to-close/ Assuming you are shorting, you sell to open and then buy to close if they option decreased in value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description given, it seems like you can combine shifting `B`, calculating a rolling max, and comparing this rolling max to the 'current' value of `B`:

```
df['D2'] = np.where((pd.Series(np.where(df['C'] == 'SELL', 
                    df['B'],
                    0)).shift(-5).rolling(5, min_periods=1).max() / df['B']) > 1.05,
                    'CLOSE',
                    '-')
print(df)
```

returns

```
            A       B     C      D     D2
0   1/05/2019  460.97     -      -      -
1   2/05/2019  454.50     -      -      -
2   3/05/2019  439.00     -      -      -
3   4/05/2019  438.04     -      -      -
4   5/05/2019  433.00     -      -      -
5   6/05/2019  428.01     -  CLOSE  CLOSE
6   7/05/2019  440.00     -      -      -
7   8/05/2019  437.69     -      -      -
8   9/05/2019  452.37  SELL      -      -
9  10/05/2019  455.93     -      -      -
```